# Using Deferred<...> in Room DAO with Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

I'm trying to use Coroutines with a Room database in an Android project. I've found almost no documentation online, and I'm wondering if it is possible to return `Deferred<>` types in those methods. Something like this:

```
@Dao
interface MyObjectDAO {

@Query("SELECT * FROM myObject WHERE id_myObject = :idMyObject")
suspend fun readMyObjectAsync(idMyObject: Int): Deferred<MyObject>
}
```

I've tried this and I get `Not sure how to convert a Cursor to this method's return type` at compile time.

My dependencies are:

```
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.1.0-alpha04'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-coroutines:2.1.0-alpha04'
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your issue lies in that you're mixing the `suspend`ing converter and the `Deferred` converter. Use one or the other and your code will work as intended.

- `fun readMyObjectAsync(idMyObject: Int): Deferred<MyObject>` - Best choice if you need to interface/be compatible with java code, since it doesn't require code transformations to actually function.
- `suspend fun readMyObjectAsync(idMyObject: Int): MyObject` - If you're operating on pure kotlin this will allow better control through the context it is called in.

Comment: That's good to know, thank you.
I've read that if I mark my DAO method with `suspend`, "by default, Room will use the Architecture Components I/O Executor as the Dispatcher to run SQL statements". [link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/room-coroutines-422b786dc4c5)
Will it do the same if I choose to forego the 'suspend' keyword and just return a Deferred<MyObject>?

Comment: Spent an hour trying to resolve this. Thanks for helping me see the mistake.