# extends java.util.List. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.?

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, kotlin-coroutines

I am developing a new android app but I am getting the following exception Unable to invoke no-args constructor for kotlinx.coroutines.Deferred>. Registering an InstanceCreator with Gson for this type may fix this problem.

below my MainViewModel.kt

```
@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
class MainViewModel(val newsRepository: NewsRepository) : ViewModel(), CoroutineScope {
    // Coroutine's background job
    val job = Job()
    // Define default thread for Coroutine as Main and add job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext = Dispatchers.Main + job

    val showLoading = MutableLiveData<Boolean>()
    val sportList = MutableLiveData <List<Article>>()
    val showError = SingleLiveEvent<String>()

    fun loadNews() {
        // Show progressBar during the operation on the MAIN (default) thread
        showLoading.value = true
        // launch the Coroutine
        launch {
            // Switching from MAIN to IO thread for API operation
            // Update our data list with the new one from API
            val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
                newsRepository?.getNewsList()
            }
            // Hide progressBar once the operation is done on the MAIN (default) thread
            showLoading.value = false
            when (result) {

                is UseCaseResult.Success<*> -> {
                    sportList.value = result.data as List<Article>
                }
                is Error -> showError.value = result.message
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCleared() {
        super.onCleared()
        // Clear our job when the linked activity is destroyed to avoid memory leaks
        job.cancel()
    }
}
```

below   appmodules.kt my  network logic implementation

```
const val BASE_URL = "https://newsapi.org/"

val appModules = module {
    // The Retrofit service using our custom HTTP client instance as a singleton
    single {
        createWebService<SportNewsInterface>(
            okHttpClient = createHttpClient(),
            factory = RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create(),
            baseUrl = BASE_URL
        )
    }
    // Tells Koin how to create an instance of CatRepository
    factory<NewsRepository> { (NewsRepositoryImpl(sportsNewsApi = get())) }
    // Specific viewModel pattern to tell Koin how to build MainViewModel
    viewModel { MainViewModel (newsRepository = get ())  }
}

/* Returns a custom OkHttpClient instance with interceptor. Used for building Retrofit service */
fun createHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
    client.readTimeout(5 * 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    return client.addInterceptor {
        val original = it.request()
        val requestBuilder = original.newBuilder()
        requestBuilder.header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        val request = requestBuilder.method(original.method, original.body).build()
        return@addInterceptor it.proceed(request)
    }.build()
}

/* function to build our Retrofit service */
inline fun <reified T> createWebService(
    okHttpClient: OkHttpClient,
    factory: CallAdapter.Factory, baseUrl: String
): T {
    val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl(baseUrl)
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(GsonBuilder().setLenient().create()))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .addCallAdapterFactory(factory)
        .client(okHttpClient)
        .build()
    return retrofit.create(T::class.java)
}
```

below SportNewsResponse.kt

```
data class SportNewsResponse(
    val articles: List<Article>,
    val status: String,
    val totalResults: Int
)
```

below SportNewsInterface where I have implemented my ending points

interface SportNewsInterface {

```
@GET("v2/top-headlines?country=us&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
suspend fun getNews(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>

@GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=espn&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
fun getEspn(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>

@GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=football-italia&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
fun getFootballItalia(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>

@GET("/v2/top-headlines?sources=bbc-sport&apiKey=da331087e3f3462bb534b3b0917cbee9")
fun getBBCSport(): Deferred<List<SportNewsResponse>>
```

}

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Deferred<...> in Room DAO with Kotlin Coroutines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55925479/using-deferred-in-room-dao-with-kotlin-coroutines)

Comment: not it did not answer my question

Comment: Your `suspend fun getNews` has exactly the problem in that question.

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: what is main problem Alexey Romanov what I have to do fix problem

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov what is your suggestion in order to fix problem

Comment: @sashabeliy Remove `suspend` from that function.